# Problem with calling a variable from one function into another

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am trying to call a variable from one function into another by using the command `return`, without success. This is the example code I have:

```
def G():
    x = 2
    y = 3
    g = x*y
    return g

def H():
    r = 2*G(g)
    print(r)
    return r
H()
```

When I run the code i receive the following error `NameError: name 'g' is not defined`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `def G():` returns a variable. Therefore, when you call it, you assign a new variable for the returned variable.

Therefore you could use the following code:

```
def H():
    G = G()
    r = 2*G
    print (r)
```

You don't need to give this statement:

```
return r
```

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful Gautam. I have one question what if I had two or more variables in the first funtion but I only want to call one of them?

Comment: Okay. First of all, you're not calling a variable. You only call a function that returns a variable, or variables. So for eg, if you want to return the x variable also, you would give, `return x, g` under `def G()`

And then, when calling that function, you would create 2 new variables for assigning the value of the 2 variables returned.

So you would say, `a, b = G()` where 'a' will get the value of 'x' and 'b' will get the value of 'g'.

Comment: Is it necessary to give different names, a and b, to the new variables or can i use the same x and g? Do you know of any good tutorial on youtube that explains funtions in depth. Sorry for the multiple questions asked.

Comment: You can use the same variable names, 'x' and 'g'. 
Also, here's the link to a playlist of Python 3 tutorial: Python 3 Basics Tutorial Series: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVp1vrfL_w4&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDe8XSftW-RAxdo6OmaeL85M

Answer (score 0):

While you've accepted the answer above, I'd like to take the time to help you learn and clean up your code.

```
NameError: name 'g' is not defined
```

You're getting this error because `g` is a local variable of the function `G()`

**Clean Version:**

```
def multiple_two_numbers():
    """
      Multiplies two numbers

      Args:
        none

      Returns:
        product : the result of multiplying two numbers
    """

    x = 2
    y = 3
    product = x*y
    return product


def main():

    result = multiple_two_numbers()
    answer = 2 * result
    print(answer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    main()
```

**Problems with your code:**

1. Have clear variable and method names. `g` and `G` can be quiet confusing to the reader.
2. Your not using the `if __name__ == "__main__":`
3. Your return in `H()` unnecessary as well as the `H()` function.
4. Use docstrings to help make your code more readable.

**Questions from the comments**:

> I have one question what if I had two or more variables in the first
>   function but I only want to call one of them

Your function can have as many variables as you want. If you want to return more than one variable you can use a dictionary(key,value) List, or Tuple. It all depends on your requirements.

> Is it necessary to give different names, `a` and `b`, to the new
>   variables or can I use the same `x` and `g`?

**Absolutely!** Declaring another variable called `x` or `y` will cause the previous declaration to be overwritten. This could make it hard to debug and you and readers of your code will be frustrated.